# Get the downloadUrl of files in google driver in C# console application

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, console-application

I am working to connect to the google drive, list every files with any formats and then download it physically on my hard. I used the methods which google API prepared for me. But I think the way I worked I just have access to the content of each file and so I can not do that.

Could you please help me to know that which configuration I need to do that?

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.FileList ListFiles(DriveService service, FilesListOptionalParms optional = null)
        {
            try
            {

                if (service == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("service");


                var request = service.Files.List();

                request = (FilesResource.ListRequest)SampleHelpers.ApplyOptionalParms(request, optional);

                return request.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Request Files.List failed.", ex);
            }
        }
```

I call this method and for each file I want to download it on my PC:

```
 FileList files_list = DriveListExample.ListFiles(service, null);
            if (files_list.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files_list.Items)
                {                        
                    DriveListExample.DownloadFile(service, file, DownloadDirectoryName);




                    Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" ", file.Title + " downloaded completely!");


                }
            }
```

here if I can access to the downloadUrl of each file I can test another way for downloading. But it is null and this is my download method:

public static void DownloadFile(DriveService service, File file, string saveTo)
    {

```
    var request = service.Files.Get(file.Id);
    var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    Console.WriteLine(file.FileExtension);


    request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
    {
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                    break;
                }
            case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                    SaveStream(stream, saveTo);
                    break;
                }
            case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                    break;
                }
        }
    };

    try
    {
        request.Download(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)

    {
        Console.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

the status of download is Failed in this process. 
I also check the scopes and I found that with these lines just allow me to download the files I created in this application:

```
private static readonly string[] Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.Drive };
```

But I need after listing all of files, I can download each of them.

Could you please help me with the solution or other working codes?

Comment: try by adding one more scope "DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly" in Scopes.

Comment: @Adrian But I don't think it solve the problem. It just access to read the file. I want to download them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a valid file name and handle google doc files:

```
 public static void DownloadFile(DriveService service, Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file, string saveTo)
        {

            var request = service.Files.Get(file.Id);
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
            // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
            // download is completed or failed.
            request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
            {
                switch (progress.Status)
                {
                    case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                            SaveStream(stream, saveTo + @"/" + file.Title);
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                        {
                            if (file.ExportLinks.Any())
                                SaveStream(new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync(file.ExportLinks.FirstOrDefault().Value).Result, saveTo + @"/" + file.Title);
                            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                            break;
                        }
                }
            };

            try
            {
                request.Download(stream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                Console.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```